# Subtraction principle

Tags: combinatorics

How many positive integers less than 10000 are there which contain a digit 2 or 3?

Is this the right derivation?
$$9\times9\times9\times8=5832$$
$$5832-2=5830$$
$$9998-5830=4168$$

Comment: Whether that is the right answer or not STOP your habit of run on equations.  $9*9*9*8 \ne 5832-2 the 5730*9*9*9*7 \ne 5103 -3$.  $9*9*9*8=5832$.  $5832-2=5830$.  $9*9*9*7=5103$.  $5103-3 =5100$.  These are all different numbers so the can't be equal to each other.

Comment: First all you give 2 answers, 5830 and 5100.  There's only one answer.  Which one?  Second.  No.  They are both completely wrong and make no sense.

Comment: I'm not talking about this problem. *NEVER* do $8*7 =56 - 4 =52/2=26+1=27$. Instead do $8*7=56$ PERIOD! $56 -4 = 52$ period. $52/2=26$ etc. $8*7 = 56$ it doesn't equal $56 -4$. You can't just finish a sentence and then go onto another sentence by adding subtracting 4. At best it makes no sense.

Comment: Let $A$ be the event "at least one $2$" and let $B$ be the event $\dots$. We  want $|A\cup B|$.  Note that for example $|A|=10^4-9^4$.

Comment: Sorry, what value are you proposing as your answer?  How did you come up with it?  Actually, I'm not even sure I know what the question is.  How does a number "contain" a $2$?  Do you mean that it has $2$ has a digit or do you mean it is divisible by $2$ or do you mean something else altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Count the complement set: the number of numbers from 0000 to 9999 with *no* 2 or 3. For each of the four places (units, tens, hundreds, thousands) there are 8 possibilities for this, so the complement number is $8^4=4096$. Subtract this from 10000 to get the answer: $10000-4096=5904$.

Comment: A friendly English tip: A clear way to state the negation of "contains a 2 or a 3" is "contains neither a 2 nor a 3".

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of naturals with at least one 2, then count the number with at least one 3 and subtract the number with boh 2 and 3